# Modelling with Curves using a bevel object

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I am trying to model this long stone bench in blender using curves. I have a made a path and the cross-section of the bench. When I select bevel object of the path as the bench's cross-section, the resulting mesh is completely flat or cubic. Can someone please let me know where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you applied Rotation for cross-section? If yes, this is a reason.

Comment: The rotation and scale for the curve and cross-section is set to 0,0,0 & 1,1,1.

Comment: Select cross-section, go to Edit Mode, select all, and try to rotate it on different axis and see what happens.

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. Actually I was rotating it in object mode previously. Now it's fine. Thanks. BTW can you please explain why does it matter rotating it in edit mode instead of object mode?

Comment: You can read about it here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html section Apply. I do not know more about it then Blender manual :)

Comment: Is that the 'String of Pearls?' ...Marine Drive?

Comment: @RobinBetts Yep. It's. Marine drive (queen's necklace) in mumbai....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit counterintuitive, bevel objects are used along the curve's local Y axis. Create both curves using the top view.

[image]

then use the bevel object.

[image]

Comment: It may be counter-intuitive, but it's consistent. If you create a custom orientation from an edge, the direction along it is considered to be Y. From a face.. the normal is considered to be Z.

Comment: Ty, this solved my problem forever.